# Cheap/free ski passes for children

Tags: europe, minors, skiing

Skiing tends to be fairly expensive sport, especially when you have a family. What is the easiest way to find out what are the ski pass prices in different resorts, and in particular which resorts offer free ski passes for children (and the age from which they need to pay)?

Comment: You might want to specify the country or the time period...

Comment: Not an answer but I have noticed that many resorts now have free areas (typically a handful of not-too-difficult tracks, often with one or two specifically dedicated to small kids) instead.

Comment: (As relaxed says, some places have totally free (ie, no pass at all) areas now for toddlers/etc. For example, there's a completely free magic carpet at I think le savoy at chamonix.)  But yeah it's a good question you want a **definitive, combined, comparison table, of ski prices, particularly with regard to family skiing**.  Great question!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to get a little more specific about areas where you wanted to ski because there are some deals that may not be published at all but there is a website I've mentioned in one of my previous answers:

- [On the Snow](http://www.onthesnow.com/skireport.html)

If you navigate to the appropriate region such as [USA](http://www.onthesnow.com/united-states/ski-resorts.html) you can see the prices for [Lift Tickets](http://www.onthesnow.com/united-states/lift-tickets.html), which lists prices for Adult and Children separately if information is available.